# Swapping between ascending and descending x axis in ggplot and barplot

Tags: r, sorting, plot, ggplot2

I know this should be simple, and it is probably asked before, but I can't find it. I have this code for a bar plot in ggplot:

```
ggplot(agg.table.year,aes(x=YR,y=prc)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100),expand=c(0,0)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',width=0.7) + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) + xlab('') + ylab('Percent') +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,hjust=1,size=13)) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=13)) +
  ggtitle("Fraction of government-funded studies
```

[image]

With the same data, x-axis (year) being a factor, the following barplot code:

```
barplot((agg.table.year$prc),axes=T,ylim=c(0,100),
        names.arg = agg.table.year$YR,
        cex.names=0.8,las=2,space=0.5,col="black",density=19,
        main=paste("Fraction of government-funded studies"))
```

gives this plot:

[image]

I am not mastering how to switch between ascending and descending x-axis in either way, but I am desperate learn. I have googled it and read the R Cookbook, but I don't get it.

Comment: Does `scale_x_reverse` do what you want?

Comment: You should include data with your question, but I am assuming that agg.table.year$YR is a factor. In which case plotting order is neither numeric nor alphabetic, but determined by order of the factors. Use YR <- order(YR) before plot to arrange years how you want – dww 5 mins ago

Comment: This is all very helpful, I am starting to understand it all. The only thing missing now is to manipulate the order for a NUMERIC year value in 'barplot'. It starts as descending, following the data file, but how do I code it to be ascending?